# Transparent PNG created in Imagemagick drawn as opaque in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, transparency

I am trying to script the creation of videos using ImageMagick to create some overlays which are then placed on top of a video.

If I try to use the image created by ImageMagick directly the transparency is drawn as opaque.

I have created a transparent PNG using ImageMagick draw commands. When loaded into GIMP and examined, the PNG has an alpha channel and each transparent pixel appears to have transparency: RGBA = 0,0,0,0

This image when then used as an overlay in ffmpeg just has an opaque black background in the video.

If I export the image again from GIMP then the file looks identical, but in the video just appears as a solid blue (the colour of the drawings in the overlay image).

I can fix this by taking the overlay image, loading it in GIMP and then selecting all and creating a new image from the clipboard and exporting that (using exactly the same settings as when I re-exported before without creating a new file) and it will then work exactly as desired, showing the non-transparent portions of the overlay and not showing transparent parts.

**KEY QUESTION:**

How can I either script the conversion that somehow occurs when creating a new file in GIMP, or (much better) not have it go wrong in the first place?

Here are the two files:

BROKEN:
[image: This does not work]
WORKS:
[image: This one does work]
What is the difference?

Comment: Why not take the image steaight from ImageMagick into `ffmpeg` and avoid `gimp` if that messes it up?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but what I meant to get across was that the original png output from ImageMagick was broken, the png opened and re-exported from GIMP was even more broken, but the thing that worked in the end was select all and copying and pasting into a new image in GIMP. I only started using GIMP once (for no apparent reason) the ImageMagic output became unusable.

Comment: I am not at my Mac to test this but try preceding the output filename in ImageMagick with `PNG32:` like this `convert xyz.png ... PNG32:output.png`

Comment: Yes, that looks like it works, fantastic. If you will put it in as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you prefix the output filename when using ImageMagick with `PNG32:` to force it to generate a 32-bit ber pixel image - i.e. 1 byte each for R, G, B and Alpha and hope that `ffmpeg` is happier with that.

```
convert input.png -draw ... PNG32:output.png
```

If you run `identify -verbose` (also in the ImageMagick suite) on your broken and your working images, you will see that the primary difference is that the working image has `color-type=6` and `bit-depth=8` whereas the broken image has `color-type=3 (indexed)` and `bit-depth=4`

[image]

Comment: I had originally been creating the overlay in ImageMagick as one PNG image and using `-define png:color-type=6`. I then moved to creating the overlay by combining images of a few hundred rectangles at once as the command line became too long, but the composited file was not made using that option. It appears ImageMagick decided to save the composite as the simplest thing it could despite the quality settings of the originals.

Comment: Adding the PNG32: prefix solved a different issue I was having with ffmpeg using the PNG sequence as an input and messing up the timebase with the ffmpeg overlay filter. ffmpeg was interpreting the PNGs as ya8 which would mess things up in the filtergraph, but forcing them to be PNG32 fixed it.